# How to maintain a single Realm instance throughout the app lifecycle and also close it?

Tags: android, realm

How can I maintain a single Realm Instance throughout the complete lifecycle of the App and also close it.

I can achieve maintaining the instance using a singleton class, but then how do I close it when the app is closed?

Also, is it safe to not close Realm Instance once opened?

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use a singleton `RealmManager` **for the UI thread**, and for background threads I open/close the Realm using a `try-with-sources` block.

So for UI thread:

```
public class RealmManager {
    private static final String TAG = "RealmManager";

    static Realm realm;

    static RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

    public static void initializeRealmConfig(Context appContext) {
        if(realmConfiguration == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Initializing Realm configuration.");
            setRealmConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(appContext).initialData(new RealmInitialData())
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .inMemory()
                    .build());
        }
    }

    public static void setRealmConfiguration(RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration) {
        RealmManager.realmConfiguration = realmConfiguration;
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }

    private static int activityCount = 0;

    public static Realm getRealm() {
        return realm;
    }

    public static void incrementCount() {
        if(activityCount == 0) {
            if(realm != null) {
                if(!realm.isClosed()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected open Realm found.");
                    realm.close();
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Incrementing Activity Count [0]: opening Realm.");
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }
        activityCount++;
        Log.d(TAG, "Increment: Count [" + activityCount + "]");
    }

    public static void decrementCount() {
        activityCount--;
        Log.d(TAG, "Decrement: Count [" + activityCount + "]");
        if(activityCount <= 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Decrementing Activity Count: closing Realm.");
            activityCount = 0;
            realm.close();
            if(Realm.compactRealm(realmConfiguration)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Realm compacted successfully.");
            }
            realm = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And for background thread:

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a wrapping class for your realm instance (may be a singleton) and then add a few methods to it, so that instead of closing realm each time you can just call your own method and close the used instance as soon as you're finished? Something like this.

```
public class WrappingRealm {
    public static WrappingRealm getInstance() {
        //create your singleton here. Be aware of synchronization issues
    }

    private Realm getRealm() {
        return Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public void save(RealmModel obj)  {
        Realm currentRealm = getRealm();

        currentRealm.executeTransaction {
            //Do your stuff
        }

        currentRealm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't opening and closing realm again and again consume more memory? maybe also a performance hit

Comment: It's a good idea to close an instance when you're done. In this case I assumed that all he's doing is saving an object, so therefore realm should be closed.

Comment: This works for saving, but it won't work for querying.

Comment: The idea is that you would create the other necessary methods within this class using the same pattern

Comment: Ya it wont work for querying, RealmList is actually a proxy list and if you close the database before you query the list, then it would crash.

Comment: is a bad idea open and close a real instance if you have many transactions , it consume too many memory